# Unsupported `const` declaration on local variable in Julia

Tags: function, variables, types, constants, julia

In Julia, I have defined a function which takes some arguments `x,y,z`, each of them doesn't change in through the process inside the function. For optimizing my program , I intended to make `x,y,z` be `const`. I did it like this:

```
function myFunc(x,y,z)
  const x = x; const y = y; const z = z;
  
  # algorithm using x,y,z
  # ...
  # ...

end
```

However, I caught an error below:

```
syntax: unsupported `const` declaration on local variable around In[55]:36
```

What is wrong?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is currently not supported, and shouldn't be needed for performance reasons (although it could be useful for catching accidentally mutating arguments). See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5148 for some more discussion.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it as using constant no longer has to do with performance when used in local scope in Julia.

Comment: Even if local `const` were allowed, wouldn't it be a problem that the code is trying to make `const` variables that share their names with input arguments?

Comment: I assume it would just be the new `x` that would be `const`.